# Erro "1146 table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Esse erro me impede de criar novas tabelas e acessar as já criadas:

[image]

Erro:

> 1146 table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking doesn't exist

Como conserto isso?

Answer (score 5):

`pma__tracking` é uma tabela de uso do **phpMyAdmin**.

Provavelmente você deletou ela por engano.

Para restaurar esta tabela, é possível importar [este arquivo](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql) que tem todas as tabelas (que é o que o **phpMyAdmin** faz na instalação). Ou pode apenas rodar apenas a `query` abaixo na base `phpmyadmin`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__tracking` (
`db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
`date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
`schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,
`schema_sql` text,
`data_sql` longtext,
`tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,
`tracking_active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`)
)
COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin'
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Isto informa que a tabela pma__tracking não existe no banco de dados phpmyadmin então vá ao seu administador de banco de dados que no caso  parece ser o phpmyadmin e verifique o  nome correto da tabela e banco caso não exista crie-os.