# PHPMyadmin Bugado

Tags: phpmyadmin

Quando tento acessar qualquer banco de dados pelo phpmyadmin o mesmo retorna o seguinte erro:

```
SELECT tracking_active FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE db_name = 'phpmyadmin'  AND table_name = 'pma__bookmark'  ORDER BY version DESC

Mensagem do MySQL: Documentação
#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

Uso Ubuntu 14.04
PHPMYADMIN Versão do servidor: 10.1.8-MariaDB - Source distribution
Uso XAMPP

Instalei a versão mais recente do Xampp e nao fiz mais nenhuma modificação após isso.

Comment: Acredito que sua pergunta seja um pouco vaga, você pode especificar em qual sistema está encontrando esta mensagem? Este sistema é Debian, Mint, etc, se for Windows, você instalou por sí próprio ou está usando uma base de desenvolvimento como Wamp, XAMP, etc? Tente reformular sua pergunta, mas pelo que parece, você instalou uma versão mais recente do phpmyadmin mas não atualizou o banco, em sistemas Unix isso já ocorre automaticamente.

Comment: Parece ser algo corrompido ou instalado pela metade.

Comment: Editei o topico ai, corrompido acho que não por que eu beixei duas vezes já.

Comment: Ou foi instalado por cima, no caso você deve deletar tudo e depois copiar os arquivos

Comment: @JoãoCarlos olha [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76585/18246)

Comment: Isso parece ter sido `override`.

Comment: Eu copiei e colei la o arquivo so create_tables.sql e não adiantou nada continua dando o mesmo erro.